# Python add dashes to your characters in a string?

Tags: python

I have a string that i want to modify.

The string is something like 0rty4653 and i want to convert it into this format :-

0--r--t--y--4--6--5--3-- or in other words make it look into the following format --[CHAR]--.

The string could be dynamic.

I converted my string into a list thus far :-

```
my_str = 0rty4653
my_list = my_str.split()
```

but how do i convert it into the above format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final = ""
for i in my_list:
   final += i+"--"
```

iterating over the list should allow you to concat each element and -- to create that product